# Next word in this progression

Tags: lateral-thinking, sequence, word-sequence

Given this ordered set of six words:
Adapt, Abbreviate, Cacao, Forbidding, Queue, Daffodil

You must discover the logical progression they follow and choose the word that should go next. Options are:
Gorge, Death, Options, Simile

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A suitable word is

> Gorge

as this follows the pattern

> **A**d**a**pt, A**bb**reviate, **C**a**c**ao, Forbi**dd**ing, Qu**e**u**e**, Da**ff**odil

where each word contains

> two occurrences of a, b, c, d, e, f, g